# Persistence does not ocur in a stateless bean, using JPA when duplicate key exception is thrown

Tags: java, jpa, javabeans, persist, stateless

In a stateless bean, i´ve persisted a customer, but when I try to persist an entity product, this trows a duplicate key exception.
So the customer is not persisted in db. Why is that?

```
@Stateless
public class WebUserServiceEjb {
public void addProductToCustomer(String customer, List<String> products) {

customerEntity = ... get customer with string customer

try {
    em.persist(customerEntity);
    em.flush();
    em.refresh(customerEntity);
    // this is ok

    prod1 = ... get entity using string fromproducts list
    em.persist(prod1);
    // this is ok
    prod2 = ... get entity using string from products list
    em.persist(prod2); //this throws an exception

} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    System.out.println('duplicate key exception persisting product')
}
```

### Output: duplicate key exception persisting product

My question is:

- Why customerEntity and prod1 are not persisted in db? The exception is handled.

I know that a solution is to ask before trying to persist, but I dont want to do that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the solution, but the specification states that any persistence exception thrown causes the transaction to be marked for rollback - which is why nothing is persisted regardless of you catching the exception or not. If you don't know that an entity exists or not and don't want to manually check yourself - what do you want to happen with the values in the prod2 instance? If you want them merged into the existing data, use JPA's merge instead of persist.

Comment: @Chris
What I want is:
customer persisted in db,
 prod1 persisted in db,
 prod2 lost.
And method ends regardless if there are more products on list.
That´s "the solution"

"the specification states that any persistence exception thrown causes the transaction to be marked for rollback"
that means that all entities are marked for rollback?

Comment: Entities aren't marked for rollback - the transaction is. The Entitymanager is a context, and persist/merge etc aren't immediate one off calls to the db - any error such as this leaves the EntityManager in a bad state; the entity is persisted (and so required to be managed) but parts may or may be in the database. For this one use case, you may know it is only that one insert that failed and want to continue, but JPA has to handle all cases, so mandates errors like this roll things back. If you don't want exceptions, check first. Alternatively write the insert yourself

Comment: @Chris write the insert myself?
I understand what you are saying, it clarifies me to think the EntityManager as a context. But, anyways it´s counter intuitive, there is no way to tell the context
"hey, put in DB all the persist that didn´t trigger a problem, but if a entity gives a problem dont commit that and just stop the method". For me to check is to boilerplate, I expect that there is some sort of configuration because is what I expect in all cases. Is something like "commit everything until something fails"

Comment: Your expectations are a bit off- Persist is stating to the context that this data doesn't exist and needs to be inserted. JPA is designed so that statements are not immediate (they only need to be issued on synchronization to the DB, so on flush or commit), and requires you to re-do the transaction on error, ensuring you have the latest state without tying up resources for a prolonged period. JPA may not be right for you; if it isn't, you can write insert statements via JDBC and handle exceptions without forcing the rollback and just use JPA where it is.

Comment: @Chris ok thanks, so the final solution is to write a fork of JPA which handles my desired use case or look for another framework.
Anyway, the answer is in the comments, should I answer my question myself and mark my own answer as correct?

Comment: JPA providers have other (non-JPA) options and api that might allow you to insert or ignore. With EclipseLink for example, you can have it issue writeObject queries on the Entity and might be able to catch the exceptions so they don't cause rollback - see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15901/queries006.htm (TopLink docs describe native EclipseLink api). Hibernate API might have similar options

Comment: So, based on Chris comments:
 * JPA can´t handle this use case.


Extra:
Another solution is to do a partition in products, for example,
sending in sets of 10 productos, or even set of 1 product to persist.
In the stateless bean, the method that persist should use: @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

That is
    @Stateless
    public class WebUserServiceEjb {
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void addSetProductToCustomer(String customer, List<String> products) {       
   
Part1

Comment: And then if I use (pseudo java notation):
addSetProductToCustomer(customer, prod1 + prod2)
addSetProductToCustomer(customer, prod3)

if prod3 throws an exception, at least prod1 and prod2 will be persisted.

Part2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best that can be done for this is to answer the question asked: Why.

JPA EntityManager [persist](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-) is defined in such a way that it is required to thrown an exception if the entity already exists - either an ntityExistsException immediately if it can be determined upfront, or any other persistence exception later on such as if it performs an insert during delayed synchronization to the database (ie flush or transaction commit).

These exceptions are not recoverable for the EntityManager, as it cannot determine what else in the context made it in - if by chance you were able to continue with the transaction, it would be required to re attempt to insert the duplicate Entity since it is within the context. It would seem that JPA took the approach of requiring the user to obtain a new context and retry rather than define additional overhead to providers (and users) to clear out particular objects on errors such as this.

What is usually done is an existence check before calling persist. In some cases, this is just a check that the Entity in question has an Identifier - if this is DB assigned, this is sometimes more than enough to know if it should use persist or perform some additional, more expensive check to determine if it should be inserted or ignored. There is no insert or ignore in JPA - but some providers do support issuing queries outside of the JPA context for you that would achieve the same ends.

Comment: Thank Chris, I think one of the most important part is this
"There is no insert or ignore in JPA", because I think that it would be a nice feature, in the problem that I´m trying to solve, I was trying to do a batch insert in the DB, and if there are some missing product, it doesn´t matter, I think that is a relative common use case.